# How do I calculate Gradient of ranking loss?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, objective-function

I am trying to understand ranking loss(a.k.a, Maximum Margin Objective Function, MarginRankingLoss ...) based on [CS 224D: Deep Learning for NLP lecture note](http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/notes3.pdf).

In this note, the cost is defined as follows: J = (1 + sc − s)

s= f(θ,x),  sc = f(θ,xc), 
x is the input of the correct, and xc is the input of the wrong.

So, s is score of good thing, sc is score of bad thing.

My question is this:
To update the weights, do I have to get  ∂J/ ∂θ or ∂s/∂θ?

I thought I had to do ∂J / ∂θ to update θ.

Therefore, since J = 1 + sc-s, ∂J / ∂θ = ∂sc / ∂θ - ∂s / ∂θ.

So I thought that ∂sc / ∂θ and ∂s / ∂θ should be obtained, respectively.

In a lecture note, however, calculate ∂J / ∂s = -1 and use this value to update the network.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: removed the tensorflow tag - please only add relevant tags to your post.  Thanks!